# Help me resolve few queries about bitcoin network ( regarding validation, mining and state of transactions...)

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

Q1. Suppose I make a transaction from node A to node B, it is gets validated by the nodes in the network, A new block hasn’t been mined yet, in the meantime miner is stashing up the transactions Miner doesn’t include my transaction in the newly minted block, what happens to my bitcoin in the time between the next miner decides to put my transaction in the next block?

Q2. Bitcoin has a public ledger, by public ledger do we mean that each node in the network has a chain of blocks, each block having a set of transactions…and all these node have the same chain of blocks associated with them?

Q3. Whilst my transaction is internally being validated by the nodes in the network (not yet accepted by the miners), is this transaction being added to the ledger of various nodes in the network?

Q4. Also, let say, some node in the network validated a transaction, will the same node propagate this result to its neighbours, and the neighbours to their neighbours?

Answer (score 1):

A1. It remains in the mempool of those nodes until a miner decides to include it in the block it's attempting to mine. Making a transaction from node A to node B is a little confusing, maybe you meant from *address* A to *address* B?

A2. Yes, nodes that share the same consensus rules (have not hard forked) will have the same blockchain (public ledger). The blockchain determines history of transactions, and ***the order in which they occurred***.

A3. Nodes will validate transactions before they enter their mempool. Miners typically will just mine the block presented by the node (with tx's chosen to maximize profitability in terms of BTC fee/kB). The transaction is not entered into the blockchain (ledger) until a miner finds a valid solution and submits that back to a node. The node then begins to propagate the new block through the network.

A4. Yes, but this does not mean that transaction has been mined in a block yet, it will just be in each node's respective mempool.